# Adding padding to bootstrap table cells

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a flask application, with a little UI. I am having some formatting issues with Table cells especially when the data in cells is too much to fit in first line and spills over.

here are the details:
1. Using Bootstrap/Bootswatch template (Bootstrap 3.0)

2. The issue:
   I am displaying a table (code below), Each row is a list of links that I generate from my jinja2 template. Things are all aligned where there are a few
   items in `<td></td>`, however if I have more items then it spills over and the 
   buttons tend to overlap and touch teach other.

I am looking for a way to maintain some alignment cell regardless of how many buttons I display on the row and maintain some padding between the buttons.

2. Code snippet

`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<th> Environment </th><th>Roles</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<h5>Some Label</h5>
</td>
<td>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY</a>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY1/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY1</a>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY2/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY2</a>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY3/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY3</a>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<h5>Another</h5>
:
</td>
 </tr>
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to get the formatting correct by setting LINE-HEIGHT

```
<td style="LINE-HEIGHT:50px">
```

So this fixed my formatting issues:

```
<td style="LINE-HEIGHT:50px">
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY</a>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY1/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY1</a>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY2/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY2</a>
 <a href="/connect/url/DUMMY3/" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" 
  data-placement="top" title="... test title" >DUMMY3</a>
 </td>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```html
<td class="pt-5"> </td> <!--Padding 5 units on top-->
<td class="pb-5"> </td> <!--Padding 5 units on bottom-->
<td class="pr-5"> </td> <!--Padding 5 units on right-->
<td class="pl-5"> </td> <!--Padding 5 units on left-->

<td class="mt-5"> </td> <!--Margin 5 units on top-->
<td class="mb-5"> </td> <!--Margin 5 units on bottom-->
<td class="mr-5"> </td> <!--Margin 5 units on right-->
<td class="ml-5"> </td> <!--Margin 5 units on left-->
```

Comment: did you look at the result of your snippet?